# Java socket - the server response is always null

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have to connect with a server (I don´t have access to the server code) but the transmission protocol (Socket) is:

> (client) --> data
>
> ack <-- (server)
>    data response <-- (server)
>
> (client) --> ack

It's assumed that the server should always respond quickly. I connect to the server, I send the data but the response is NULL and if I debug my code, an exception occurs when I catch the response:
"java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed"

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        String order = "datahere";
        String responseServer;   
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
        InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("XXX.XX.XX.XX", 9300);
        clientSocket.connect(sa,500);

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());   
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));    
        outToServer.writeBytes(order);   
        responseServer = inFromServer.readLine();//exception if I try to debug my code   
        System.out.println("From server: " + responseServer); //responseServer is NULL
        clientSocket.close(); 

    } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
    }

}
```

That's wrong? Any idea?

I tried to disable the firewall and also add a rule for the port 9300 but the result is the same.

The client gave me an example code in Vb.Net that it's supposed to work and I try to replicate it in Java.

Code in Vb.Net:

```
Dim message As String = "datahere";

 Try
     Dim data As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message)

     Dim client As New TcpClient(ip, port)
     Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)

     data = New [Byte](2048) {}

     Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty
     Dim bytes As Integer = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
     responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)

     stream.Close()
     client.Close()

 Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket();
InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("XXX.XX.XX.XX", 9300);
clientSocket.connect(sa,500);

clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(order.getBytes("ASCII"));

byte[] data = new byte[2048];
int bytes = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(data, 0, data.length);
String responseData = new String(data, 0, bytes, "ASCII");
System.out.println("From server: " + responseData);

//Another way to catch the response:
//InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
//int data1 = in.read();
//while(data1 != -1) {
//   System.out.print((char) data1);
//   data1 = in.read();
//}

clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: `System.out.println("From server: " + responseServer);` always returns `From Server: null` ?

Comment: Yes, "responseServer" is always NULL. I don´t have access to the server code but the server should always respond so the problem must be in my code...

Comment: that means sending `datahere` to the server should make it returning your data?

Comment: "datahere" is a String with information which the server processes it. The server responds me with other text ("order success", "wrong order", etc, etc) and it should always return a response. Never a Null

Comment: does the vb code result in a null response from the server?

Comment: I don´t have knowledge of Vb but the client, who give me this code, told me it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a translation of your `VB code` in `java`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String order = "datahere";

    // Try-with-resource statement will close your socket automatically
    try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket("XXX.XX.XX.XX", 9300)) {
        // Send to the sever the order encoded in ASCII
        clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(order.getBytes("ASCII"));
        // Sleep until we have bytes to read available
        while (clientSocket.getInputStream().available() == 0) {
            Thread.sleep(100L);
        }
        // Create the buffer of exactly the amount of bytes available without blocking
        byte[] data = new byte[clientSocket.getInputStream().available()];
        // Read the bytes from the server and put it into the buffer
        int bytes = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(data, 0, data.length);
        // Decode what has been read from the server that was encoded in ASCII
        String responseData = new String(data, 0, bytes, "ASCII");
        System.out.println("From server: " + responseData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but it remains indefinitely in line: "int bytes = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(data, 0, data.length);"

Comment: try this new version

Comment: Never exits the loop While. I'll talk to my client because I start to think that maybe the problem is not mine. Thanks for you help. I will update this post

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I find the solution using your first solution. On the one hand, if is the data is wrong, the server doesn´t respond (the specifications which the client gave me, were wrong) and on the other hand I must not use "while (clientSocket.getInputStream().available() == 0)" because it closes the connection. I'll edit my post with the solution.

Comment: @josekron great news

Answer (score 0):

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    while(dis.available()>0){
    //reads characters encoded with modified UTF-8
    String temp = dis.readUTF();
    System.out.print(temp+" ");
        }
```

try to use a `dataInputStream` instead of `bufferedReader` and use `readUTF()` method in `dataInputStream` to read UTF characters.

Comment: I remove "new InputStreamReader" because DataInputStream needs an InputStream, not an InputStreamReader (DataInputStream dis =  new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream())). But never comes into the WHILE.

Comment: Thanks for you help but in your solution  the response "DataInputStream dis" is always -1 so never comes into the "While". I still haven´t resolved the problem. I will update this post.